# Use Transformer Prime instead of virtual emulator

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, usb-debugging

I am thinking about buying the Asus Transformer Prime, to start developing on android. Currently I am borrowing a Motorola Xoom to develop, and that has a Micro USB port, that I can plug into, and use it to debug my apps. From what I can tell the Asus Transformer Prime does not have such a port. Can I even use this as my debugging device, or would I be making a $500 mistake?

Comment: Shopping recs are off-topic, so I removed that bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Prime uses a proprietary cable, but it supports a USB connection to a computer via that cable (which you can see in [this image from Engadget](http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2011/12/img9240.jpg) which I posted in [another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18285/charging-the-asus-transformer-prime/18287#18287)). The fact that the connector isn't a micro USB port has no bearing on whether or not you can connect over USB (see: every Samsung tablet).

Comment: Great answer, and thank you! Do you know if the cable comes with the prime?

Comment: @ReidKersey: As far as I know it does. That picture was everything that comes in the box, as I recall, and the wall charger is basically just an AC adapter that the USB cable plugs into.

Comment: I do development using the TF-101 and it works fine, and several times faster than the emulator.